# How can I create a text-message like system with very low latency?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, cordova

I am creating an app with PhoneGap, which needs to act kind of like a texting app. The problem I am having is with latency, and data usage. I have tried polling, but its to slow and used to much data, websockets, but AppFog doesn't support them, i have also tried others but none seem to work. How would a text-message like system this be best accomplished with a PhoneGap app, javascript, and any type of backend(currently using node, but can change)? Also how can a PhoneGap app get notifications while in the background?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Phonegap plugin for push notifications on Android (you didn't say which platforms your app was intended for...), and I think also one for iOS.

[Socket.io](http://socket.io/) is a great library that uses websockets if possible, but will fall back to Ajax long polling if necessary. That should avoid the data usage problem of repeated polling. Having a connection open for minutes or hours probably isn't going to work, though.

You'll probably have to blend the two approaches. When the user is in the app, use socket.io to achieve low latency when they're actually watching. When the user is not in the app, you can afford the small amount of extra latency required to do push notifications, since they won't know that the person actually sent the message twenty seconds ago.